# Facebook, javascript: Function with userID as parameter that returns name

Tags: javascript, facebook

It is possible to make a javascript function with an user id as parameter, that will RETURN the user's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the FB.api call is asynchronous, it's a little tricky to get it to simply return a user name. Depending on what you wanted to do with the name (populate a text field, display to the user, etc) you could pass in a callback function to be called once the name was retrieved. Something like this?

```
function getName(userId, callbackFunction) {
    FB.api('/' + userId, function(response) {

        callback(response.name)
    })
}
```

and you would use it like this

```
getName(YOUR_USER_ID, function(name) {
    alert(name)
})
```

Comment: Well, that what I'm trying to avoid. I need a method where i don't have to do the callback, just to return directly the name from the id. Hope it's possible somehow.

Comment: Give me an example of what you're trying to do and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Well i have a complex function where i get all the messages (stream) exchanged by the members of a certain group, and then put them in a json. I worked with ID's ( for obvious reasons) and now i need a simple method that will help me put in the json the name instead of the ID.

Comment: Any ideas, any way i could return the name?

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.api(idUser, function(response) {
    alert("Name: "+ response.name + "\nFirst name: "+ response.first_name + "ID: "+response.id);
    var img_link = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+response.id+"/picture"
});
```

like this

source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/